# Yocto - configuration for different hardware

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, devices, yocto

I am new to Yocto and only really getting into it.

Let's say i develop a customized kernel image with a specific BSP for a product with an ARM device with various connected peripherals, and it all works well.

Then at one stage, I decide to change just one I2C device such as an LED display which in this case requires a new different kernel driver. Of course I must add this driver into the Yocto build system and do a build again?

However, what if I want to be able to easily switch between using the two devices? Does it mean that I will have to build and maintain two separatae Yocto images - one for use with the old I2C device, and one for use with the new I2C device? I am not sure how this works.

Comment: *Of course I must add this driver into the Yocto build system and do a build again?* Is that a question or a statement?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for your reply.  Ok, I agree that the way i wrote that is ambiguous. Definitely I must get the new driver into the build system, but I guess that I would have to completely rebuild the Linux image again with Yocto then? Not sure. Then If I  want to switch back to using the older device and driver, how easy can I switch this? Does it also mean doing a completely different build for each image.. one with the older device / driver , and one with the newer device / driver

Comment: Good news: no, you don't. You only need to build the kernel module, or if it actually changes the kernel, the kernel component, then rebuild the initrd (if any). Then, depending on how you plan ship the things, you'd bitbake the final image file, or just generate an updating package for the package manager inside the image (if any). It really depends on what you're doing! If your device is aware of which one it is, it can in software decide to load or not load the new kernel module, so that you wouldn't need two different images – but having two different images wouldn't hurt much, either.

Comment: @MarcusMüller So the two different drivers will be in the image? Then how do I configure it to load the right driver at startup?

Comment: That would be up to you – I don't know your driver or how your hardware knows which of two versions it is.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Could I use the device tree to specify this? What about Kconfig?

Comment: `Kconfig` is used to enable the driver (either built into the kernel or built as a loadable module). If your driver(s) have `OpenFirmware` support then yes, you can use the device tree - a different one for each hardware config, usually loaded by the boot code (`u-boot`?) and passed to the kernel. If not, the driver might be configured as a platform device (an older method of the boot code passing device info to the kernel).

Comment: Or as a last resort it could be hard-wired in the driver or via `Kconfig` (in which case you would need a different kernel for each hardware config). Once the driver probes the hardware and determines which devices are present, something like `udev` might create the `/dev` entries etc, and/or stuff will likely appear in `/sys` (assuming it is mounted). Lots of options ...